# ADMG0007E: The configuration data type ConfigSynchronizationService is not valid

Tags: deployment, websphere, continuous-deployment

I'm trying to automize WebSphere Deployment process for zero down-time using steps which you can find in [this link](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS7K4U_9.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.zseries.doc/ae/trun_ha_approllout.html)..
According to documentation's first step , we should disable "**Automatic Synchronization**" for each node. To automize it, I'm using script which given in documentation but when I try to apply the command below :

set syncServ [$AdminConfig list ConfigSynchronizationService $na_id]

I'm facing with an error that : **ADMG0007E: The configuration data type ConfigSynchronizationService is not valid**

As I checked IBM documentations, I couldn't see any resource which referred to this problem.
Does anyone have any workaround or direct solution for it?

Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

**PS**: I should mention that document written for zOS system but I'm trying to apply that methodology to WebSphere AS on Linux.

Comment: The 'ConfigSynchronizationService' type is available on WAS ND only. Are sure that your installation is ND, not Base/Developer?

Comment: Hello Marcin,
As you see image in [link](https://ibb.co/gkK8qv) which including versionInfo.bat output, it's ND type.